# detect closing current tab on browser and call ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am working on a website, where at a time one admin can login. I implemented this by saving value in database. Now the problem is when current admin forget to logout, the value in database do not change and another admin can't login again. Even this current admin can't login later on, cause the value in database is checked in condition.
I have looked in `window.onbeforeload` and `window.onunload` functions, but it only trigger on page refresh etc, not detecting browser close tab/window. I want to detect closing browser tab and call function upon close, so I can change value in database using ajax.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What if power is shutdown ? You need another solution. Maybe a timestamp to see if user is inactive.

Comment: How timestamp can be used for user inactive check?

Comment: Consider that each page updates that timestamp(on user's table on database) with the current time. When user will log on and the login system checks that the user is *active*, it has a second check that if the timestamp is older than a given time(e.g. 5 minutes), then perform the log on.

Answer (score 0):

The event you are looking for is **onbeforeunload**

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.uneforeunload` which  is trigged when tab/window is closed.

**Updated**

```
 window.onbeforeunload  = function (){
  // update your database from here before page closed
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T7GCm/)

Comment: How to call any function on `Leave Page` button? Like I want to update database.

Comment: Please have a look updated answer.

Comment: It worked on closing tab but it also triggered on navigating to another page inside site. Which is not required. Any solution to bypass other events, just close tab?